# C# program to run on window mobile 5.0 to scan QR code

Tags: c#

im new in window CE application development. i need to develop a windowCE application using visual studio 2008 professional edition. i have installed windows mobile device center, windowsCE emulator 3.0.the program should allow user to scan a QRcode using MC70(windows mobile 5.0 device). the QR code information will be display and store in to database.

through my research, i downloaded and installed the software needed to develop a window CE program. the next stage now is to program it out. i could not find a complete sample code or complete QR code related library.

any one can help me with this issue? really need help to develop a QR code scanning program in C# to run on Window CE platform.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210652/window-ce5-0-application-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You asked a very similar question a few days ago where I suggested you should download the Motorola EMDK.

*Do not use the emulator - it doesn't work with manufacturer-specific APIs. Debug on the device directly!*

The Motorola EMDK for .NET includes several samples that show you how to write programs to scan a barcode. Please note that for your scenario to work, you must use the device's imager, not the 1D laser scanner unit.

On my Win7 64 machine these samples can be found in `C:\Users\Public\Motorola EMDK for .NET`.

Comment: The imager unit (given that it can read QR code), simply returns the QR code content without you having to do anything. Look at some sample that uses the imager and see whether you can scan a QR code. Ideally there's not much you need to do.